# VB6 Exe not running another computer showing runtime error

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

My Visual Basic 6 EXE is not running on another machine...

I have built a VB6 EXE and put in a server.

Both in server and my local system, the EXE is running successfully. But when I am trying to run the exe inside the server computer, from my local system, it is some time running , sometime not running (most of the times it is not running).

All DLL files are properly configured, I cross-checked.

It is showing the error message (as per my code, error message must populate at any stage) as : `Run time error '-2147467259(80004005)'`

Comment: Are the vb6 runtimes installed on this other pc of yours?

Comment: For all we know "server" here means "file server" and that brings up its own can of worms.

Comment: can you ask for detail information and a technical report when the error occurs? that might show you the function which was causes the error ... maybe have a look here: http://visualbasic.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/visualbasic-l/runtime-error-2147467259-80004005-encountered-at-vb-4927836

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to download and install the runtime files on the machine that doesn't have VB6 installed?

You can find the setup for the runtime files here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24417

Comment: Hi Vbguyny, thanks for reply...all files were installed...I cross checked...

Issue was previous day,due to some configuration in clients's sql machine, they moved all the development database to some other physical server location...the database became slow as a result

Comment: Was there a description along with the error number? Do you happen to have any error handling in the code that can assist?